# Test for differences in coefficients across groups in panel data

Tags: t-test, panel-data, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I am wondering how to test for differences in regression coefficients across groups **in panel data** (after a fixed-effects regression).

Particularly, I can't think of a solution of how to construct interaction terms if the groups you are interested in are **not** the same than the groups that you set your fixed-effects at.

**Example:**

You have two types of survey respondents (2 groups): adults and children. They answer questions about different sorts of ice-cream (fixed effects at ice-cream level). 
The panel data set for a simple fixed-effects regression would look like this (all variables aggregated over adults and children):

```
   +----------------------------------------+
   | day | ice-cream | rating | cost  | size| 
   |-----+-----------+--------+-------+-----+
1. |  1  |  choco    |  1     |  4    |  3  | 
2. |  1  |  hazelnut |  9     |  2    |  1  | 
3. |  2  |  hazelnut |  3.5   |  1    |  1  | 
4. |  3  |  berry    |  3.5   |  5    |  2.5| 
5. |  3  |  vanilla  |  4     |  3    |  2  | 
etc |  . |  ......   |  .     |  .    |  ...| 
   +----------------------------------------+
```

How could you include interactions terms for adults and children in your regression?

I could run the regressions separately on two datasets (one for adults, one for children), but how could I test for significant differences then?

Thank you very much!

I asked a similar [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78431/compare-coefficients-across-groups-in-panel-data-set), but maybe this was too detailed or not clear enough..

**EDIT in response to @vinnief:**
I want to outline how I understand @vinnief's suggestions by illustrating the potential structure of the resulting data set. I forgot to mention that the dependent variable (rating) is not derived from the respondents' answers (imagine a gourmet magazine which rated the ice-cream types. but still the rating varies over time).

The first suggestion was

> making a new "individuals" index, which is ice-cream type*child/adult,
>   so separate the data into twice as many rows

```
   +----------------------------------------------------------------+
   | day | ice-cream_GROUP | rating | cost  | size|d_adult | d_child|
   |-----+-----------+--------+-------+-----+-----+-------+---------+
1. |  1  |  choco_adult    |  1     |  2    |  3  |  1    |    0    |
2. |  1  |  hazelnut_adult |  9     |  3    |  4  |  1    |    0    |
3. |  1  |  hazelnut_child |  9     |  4    |  1.4|  0    |    1    |
4. |  3  |  choco_adult    |  3.5   |  5    |  1.5|  1    |    0    |
5. |  3  |  choco_child    |  3.5   |  3    |  2  |  0    |    1    |
etc|  .  |  ......         |  .     |  .    |  ...|  1    |    0    |
   +------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Is this what you mean? I don't understand how I would need to set up the fixed effects regression in order to test for differences in coefficients for adults versus children?

The second suggestion was

> what if you leave the index as is, but separate child and adult
>   ratings into separate columns? Would that help you?

```
   +------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
   | day | ice-cream | rating | cost_adult  | cost_child | size_adult | size_child|
   |-----+-----------+--------+-------+-----+------------+------------+-----------+
1. |  1  |  choco    |  1     |     2       |     1      |      0      |     0    |
2. |  1  |  hazelnut |  9     |     3       |     4      |      4      |     1.4  |
3. |  3  |  choco    |  1     |     5       |     3      |      1.5    |     2    |
etc|  .  |  ......   |  .     |     .       |     .      |      .      |     .    |
   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Are you suggesting to run a fixed-effects regression with **all** independent variables (cost_adult,cost_child,size_adult,size_child)? How would I test for differences in coefficients between adults and children then? Again, a big thank you for helping me!

Comment: Can't you work with an unbalanced panel, where some periods miss, and use a dummy for adult as @Nick Stauner suggests?

Comment: Thanks vinnief! The panel is already unbalanced - so this would not cause major problems I guess. But I feel my major problem is not clear yet: There are adults and children responses in every time period (though there may be 20 adults and 10 children on day 1, and 40 adults and 4 children on day 2,etc)..how would the dummy look like? The independent variables (like ice-cream cost or ice-cream size) are the mean of the responses. I could take all responses (one dataset) or separate by adults and children (two datasets)..but would an adult dummy in a panel data set work?Thank you all very much!

Comment: If you want the interaction of ice-cream and child/adult, I would suggest making a new "individuals" index, which is ice-cream type*child/adult, so separate the data into twice as many rows. Otherwise, what if you leave the index as is, but separate child and adult ratings into separate columns? Would that help you? It would help to know what is the dependent variable.

Comment: @vinnief: the dependent variable is rating (this variable does not stem from the respondents' answers. It's set by a third party). I edited my original post and illustrated the datasets resulting from you suggestion.

Comment: any ideas how to proceed regarding the edits I made in my original post?

Comment: I'm still pretty confused about the meanings of the levels of your variables; for one thing, are they ordinal or nominal? In either case, I'm still thinking a mixed-design ANOVA (or ANCOVA if you have a continuous covariate) would be more straightforward if you're having trouble with coding your polytomous variables and interactions. I think I'd need to know the levels and organization of them in your data before I could help further with coding.

Answer (score 2):

A simple but probably imperfect option for separate datasets (or even ones you don't actually have, if you at least have the necessary sample statistics) would be to construct confidence intervals and determine what level of confidence you can achieve about your coefficient estimates before the confidence intervals overlap. I've used this method once myself. It ought to tell you roughly equivalent information to that of a more formal significance test you might wish to use instead (I've found such a test elusive, personally, as has a colleague of mine with lots of experience in regression).

I think @DLDahly answered your question about interaction terms fairly well in his comment on your last post (which one might argue you've mostly duplicated here, which isn't accepted practice). Why not dummy-code your two age groups (if they're each homogeneous enough and not dichotomized spuriously), use this binary variable and its product with the other variable (assuming you're coding it right too, if it's nominal data), and investigate the interaction term's contribution to the model that way?

[This page](http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~mauro/psy612/CATVAR.htm) gives an example of dummy-coded variables and interactions toward the bottom. If both of your variables are nominal, and you have repeated measures from certain subjects, you might consider dropping the regression approach and using a [mixed-design ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-design_analysis_of_variance) too.

Comment: Thank you Nick! Your solution with the confidence intervals sounds promising. Can you please elaborate on @DLDahly's idea with the dummy-coding of the variables? I also think this goes into the right direction! But if I have a response from group A and a response from group B for day 3 and ice-cream Vanilla, how would a dummy-coded dataset look like? This is, where I'm stuck.. Appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Because I can only have one observation per time-unit and ice-cream, otherwise the data is not in panel format anymore.

Comment: Edited in a brief response as a third paragraph. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Nick! I understand how to use interaction-terms in a 'standard' regression. What is puzzling me, is, how to keep the panel structure while using interaction terms. If I have two groups of respondents (for whom I want to test for difference in coefficients), I always have two observations/responses per time-unit and fixed-effect level (here: ice-cream). Panel data only allows for ONE observation per time-unit and fixed-effect level.